# Using JQuery to Unbind a Group of Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have the below jQuery script that binds a group of check boxes when the value test is selected from the dropdown list of the select html element.  As a result, the check boxes act like radio buttons where one checkbox can be checked at one time.  My issue is that I need the radio buttons to go back to their default behavior when selecting another value from the select box after the test value has been selected and I can't seem to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please see my below javascript and html code.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
$('input.example').prop('checked', false); 

if(this.value == 'test')
{
alert("Hello");
$('input.example').bind('change', function() {
    $('input.example').not(this).attr('checked', false);  
});

}

else if(this.value != 'test')
{
alert("Bye");
$('input.example').unbind('change', function() {
    $('input.example').not(this).attr('checked', false);  
});    

}
});
```

```html
<select id="myselect" name="action">
<option value="" selected="selected">-------------</option>
<option value="deleted_selected">Delete selected Clients</option>
<option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="button" title="Run the selected action" name="index" value="0">Go</button>
<br><br>


<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can namespace your change handler so that you are referring to the same function when you unbind it. Instead of 'change' I used 'change.myChange' as the change event to distinguish it so that it can be easily unbound later.  Otherwise you are actually creating an identical function then trying to unbind that instead of the one that you created and bound to the event.  I hope this helps.

```js
 $('select').on('change', function() {
    $('input.example').prop('checked', false); 
    if(this.value == 'test') {
      $('input.example').bind('change.myChange', function() {
        $('input.example').not(this).attr('checked', false);  
      });
    } else if(this.value != 'test') {
      $('input.example').unbind('change.myChange');    
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect" name="action">
<option value="" selected="selected">-------------</option>
<option value="deleted_selected">Delete selected Clients</option>
<option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="button" title="Run the selected action" name="index" value="0">Go</button>
<br><br>


<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(function () {

  $('select').on('change', function () {
    $('input.example').prop('checked', false);
    if (this.value == 'test')
    {
      alert('Hello');
      $('input.example').bind('change', changeHandler);
    } 
    else if (this.value != 'test')
    {
      alert('Bye');
      $('input.example').unbind('change', changeHandler);
    }
  });
  function changeHandler() {
    $('input.example').not(this).attr('checked', false);
  }

});
```

Here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wyd2206c/

Answer (score 0):

Will you expect like this?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('select').on('change', function() {
  if(this.value == 'test')
  {
   $('input.example').attr('type', 'radio'); 
   $('input.example').attr('checked', false);  
  }else if(this.value != 'test')
  {
   $('input.example').attr('type', 'checkbox');  
   $('input.example').attr('checked', false);
  }
 });
});
</script>

<select id="myselect" name="action">
<option value="" selected="selected">-------------</option>
<option value="deleted_selected">Delete selected Clients</option>
<option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="button" title="Run the selected action" name="index" value="0">Go</button>
<br><br>


<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
```